# Node.js & Less: New to both, how to get my CSS to compile?

Tags: node.js, less

So I'm taking over design of a website that a developer (who I can't contact) left. He used Node.js and LESS.

I'm somewhat familiar with Node (how it works but I'm not a developer) and I usually use Sass. Anyways, none of my CSS changes show, which makes me think that it's not compiling right.

I honestly need a 101 answer. I don't even know where my changes should be added and how to compile. I added a screenshot of the structure of the CSS above.

Here is what the structure looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUNeL.png

Can anyone help me?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

The changes should go in the .less files. To compile them to .css files you need to:

1. download and install node.js from https://nodejs.org
2. open a terminal in the root folder of your project (there should be a package.json file)
3. run `npm install` to install the dependencies listed in the package.json
4. in the package.json could be a section `"scripts": {"build-css": "lessc ..."}`
5. run `npm run build-css` to execute the command